# How to filter from text c++

Tags: c++, string

Okay imagine

```
string a = "msg|`4UPDATE REQUIRED!`` : The `$V3.82`` update is now available for your device.  Go get it!  You'll need to install it before you can play online.";
```

I want to get the **"`$V3.82``"** from string a

How can i do that?

Comment: What have you tried and where have you stuck?

Comment: What exact characteristics of that part of the string tell you it's what you want? Are you looking specifically for the pattern of backtick followed by dollar sign? If so, that should be pretty easy. If not, how do you distinguish exactly what you are looking for?

Comment: yep can be filtered by pattern

Answer (score 0):

you can use the substr function

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        string a = "msg|`4UPDATE REQUIRED!`` : The `$V3.82`` update is now available for your device.  Go get it!  You'll need to install it before you can play online.";
string result = a.substr(31,32);
cout << result <<endl;
}
```

**OUTPUT:`$V3.82``**

Comment: STRING CLASS HAS PLENTY OF USE FULL FUNCTIONS LIKE SUBSTR THE VALUE OF RESULT WILL BE `$V3.8.2``